# Intel AVX Intrinsics to AARCH64 Platform

Tags: assembly, intrinsics, avx, arm64

I am trying to port Intel AVX intrinsics to a arm64 platform. My code contains _mm256_loadu_pd, _mm256_stream_pd, and __m256d types. Is there a existing solution available that maps these intrinsics to the aarch64 platform? Any help would much appreciated.

Comment: I don't think so.  Intrinsics are called intrinsics because they are intrinsic to one architecture.

Comment: This question is way too broad.  Either narrow it down to a specific function, or ask separate questions about NT stores, and about 256-bit vector width.  (I think I read something about ARM having scalable vector width somehow, so code could take advantage of hardware with wider than 128-bit vectors.)

Comment: @PeterCordes SVE is a rather recent instruction set extension.  I'm not sure how wide-spread it is already.

Comment: @fuz: Do you know if any ARM uarches actually have 256-bit vector hardware, or if using SVE now is just a way to take advantage of *future* hardware without recompiling?

Comment: @PeterCordes As far as I know it's the later.  Though I suspect that people are going to assume a size of 128 bit in their code, rendering the whole point of this extension moot.